# Does a flexible (e.g. DHCP) Windows multihomed wifi adapter configuration exist?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, multi-homed

**Given Location Configuration**

- Internet & wifi modem address: 192.168.0.1 no DHCP
- iDrac remote server access: 192.168.0.250
- Firewall router with NAT:  192.168.0.254 ->  192.168.5.0/24 DHCP &
  reserved

**Question part A:**  Previously I have always kept the inside firewall traffic (192.168.5.0/24) on a physically separate lan/wifi.  This location has a telephone company modem with wifi built in, so both the 192.168.0.0/24 and the 192.168.5.0/24 traffic share the same physical (lan/wifi) media.  It seems to me that this compromises the firewall's security at least to some degree.  *The question is does it make it worthless?*

**Some facts and problem description (at least as I know them)**

- DHCP only allows one address to be assigned to a NIC/MAC/network adapter.
- With a static primary address Windows allows you to specify additional IP addresses under "Advanced TCP/IP Settings" for TCP/IPv4.
- I want my laptop wifi adapter configured with DHCP or at least I want to continue having the ability to take it anywhere and have it connect and get an address by automatically switching from static to DHCP.
- At the described location as described above I would like it to have two IP addresses, one in each network space.  This would make it possible for the laptop to still access the iDrac remote server access when the firewall router is down. (I have tested this with static IPs.)

**Question part B:**  *Is there any way in Windows [8.1 in particular] to do this configuration?*

Since DCHP doesn't support multiple addresses I have researched adding a second address permanently which evidently was possible with Windows XP.

I thought of trying to add some sort of virtual NIC/MAC which could be assigned a second address independently.

Lastly, some sort of location based utility might work (i.e. overriding IP addresses on a given SSID) and I have looked at some but they only supported one address.